# How to convert a Excel row to a single csv text cell (inverse of "Text to Columns)

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a POS program that allows me to import stock items from a csv file. The problem is that it only accepts a certain csv format.

I have a Excel spreadsheet that saves my stock in different columns with applicable column headings. Even if I save that as a csv file the POS program can not import it as such. I would like to know how to convert following Excel spreadsheet (5 columns):

[image]

to (1 column):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation is the keyword here.
You can either use the actual [`concatenate` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx), or do it using the Ampersand.

```
=concatenate(A1,",""",B1,""",""",C1,""",""",D1,""",""",E1,"""")
```

Or simply do this, which makes it easier to tell the concatenation and the inserted commas apart.

```
=A1&","""&B1&""","""&C1&""","""&D1&""","""&E1&""""
```

However, this might not be the best solution for your problem, it just answers your question. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use TEXTJOIN(...) formula (in my OFFICE 2019) for concatenating a list or range of text strings using a delimiter. It's very useful and applicable.

Comment: `TEXTJOIN` can be useful, sometimes. Can you show how to use it to answer *this* question? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score -1):

Found this answer in another answer ([How do you force excel to quote all columns of a CSV file?](https://superuser.com/questions/130592/how-do-you-force-excel-to-quote-all-columns-of-a-csv-file))

This page also has the solution which comes straight from the horse's mouth:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291296/en-us

If the link degrades, the topic to search for is:

"Procedure to export a text file with both comma and quote delimiters in Excel" and/or "Q291296"